# Registration necessary for new Offers schema?

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

Is the "Registration with Google" process that's necessary for Quick Actions also necessary to participate in the Offers schema for the new Promotions tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emails that include the Offer schema and that are classified as Promotions by Gmail ignore the registrations requirements.

We'll update the docs to make this clear.